# Access event type details with query from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civievent, api, plugin

I'm writing a WordPress plugin to display a list of CiviCRM Events, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to obtain the label for the event type. I can retrieve the list of events, and the `event_type_id`, but I haven't figured out how to retrieve the label for the event type.

```
    $eventList = CRM_Event_BAO_Event::getCompleteInfo();

    foreach ( $eventList as $event ) {
        // Upon further testing, the following returns a blank
        $type = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'event_type_id', $event );

        $typeLabel = // This is where it falls apart...

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field in the output from getCompleteInfo() is "event_type" not "event_type_id", but note that `CRM_Event_BAO_Event::getCompleteInfo()` is an internal function that just happens to be available, so you might prefer to use the api:

```
$eventList = \Civi\Api4\Event::get()->addSelect('*', 'event_type_id:label')->execute();
foreach ($eventList as $event) {
  $typeLabel = $event['event_type_id:label'];
}
```

It's also easier to discover what fields are available with the api, using the Support - Developer menu in civi.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was having a difficult time finding documentation, but I realize now I was looking for the wrong thing. Time to update my code!